# friends function program not producing the values desired in the main function?

Tags: c++

I would like the cout statements to produce the values in the main()function like this:

Customer ID:1234

City:Gastonia

State:North Carolina

zip code: 28054

I'm assuming it's a simple fix, however I'm about spent and ready to throw in the towel.  I'm running on fumes.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
     #include<iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class City;
class Customer
{
private:
int customerNumber;
int zipcode;
public:
Customer(int number, int zip)
{
    customerNumber = number;
    zipcode = zip;
}
friend void display(Customer customer, City city);
};
class City
{
private:
string city;
string state;
public:
City(string C, string S)
{
    city = C;
    state = S;
}


friend void display(Customer customer, City city);

};

void display(Customer customer, City city)
{
cout << "Customer Number: " << endl;
cout << "City: " << endl;
cout << "State: " << endl;
cout << "Zip code: " << endl;
}

int main()
{
Customer customer(1234, 28054);
City city("Gastonia", "North Carolina");
display(customer, city);

return 0;
```

Comment: your `display` function does not output anything besides the header string. I guess you meant something like this: cout << "City: " `<< city.city` << endl;

Comment: Can you be bothered to fix that horrible formatting please?

Comment: Thanks Serge!  Thanks Mark!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display` isn't actually accessing the fields from the objects. Simple fix:

```
void display(Customer customer, City city) {
    cout << "Customer Number: " << customer.customerNumber << endl;
    cout << "City: " << city.city << endl;
    cout << "State: " << city.state << endl;
    cout << "Zip code: " <<  customer.zipcode << endl;
}
```